# Created Exe of Spring boot application Using GraalVM, It will immediately terminate after start

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, native-maven-plugin

Created Exe of Spring boot application Using GraalVM, It will immediately terminate after start

Build is successful
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzhrN.png)

Stop exe immediately automatically  after I tried to start
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8u8H.png)

I am using below pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kpit.diagnostics.tf2</groupId>
    <artifactId>tf2-product-launcher-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tf2-product-launcher-application</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This copies the JRE used to do the build from java.home - should be 32 bit Windows JRE -->
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/win32/java</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${java.home}</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.kpit.tf2.configuration.Application</mainClass>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <buildArg>-H:EnableURLProtocols=http</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>-J-Xdebug</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>-J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>-H:-CheckToolchain</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>--initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback</buildArg>
                                <buildArg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/reflection-config.json</buildArg>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Using configuration class which will create bean

```
package com.kpit.tf2.configuration;

import com.kpit.tf2.application.lifecycle.implementation.backend.ServiceTesterLifeCycleManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class WrapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Application getApplicationBean() {
        return new Application();
    }
    
    @Bean
    ServiceTesterLifeCycleManager getServiceTesterLifeCycleManager() {
        return new ServiceTesterLifeCycleManager();
    }
    
}
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="logs" />
    <property name="MIN_INDEX" value="1" />
    <property name="MAX_ZIP_FILES" value="10" />

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" level="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="ERROR" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.kpit" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="WARNING" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.kpit" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="WARNING" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

reflection-config.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  }
]
```

All above mentioned files present in the src/main/resources folder

Expectation
1.The generated exe should be keep on running state using application.properties file
1.It should use the application.properties file which contains server.port = 9090

Note - Not getting any error but it will auto terminate if I run exe which is not expected

Can someone please help me here to find the issue.